# jquery ajax post not working with .load in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, load

i wish to .load multiple views result with jquery ajax

the original code (js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#uid").change(

function(){

    var uid=$("#uid").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?= site_url('sp_profile/ajax_userdetail') ?>",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "uid="+uid,
    cache:false,
    success:
      function(data){

        $("#content").html(data);
      }

    });

  return false;

});
});
```

this return only one result in `<div id="content"></div>`

what if i want to load 3 results like in

```
<div id="content"></div> 
<div id="content1"></div> 
<div id="content2"></div>
```

- content could be userid
- content2 could be user first name
- content3 could be user last name

my js should using .load instead of html right? let me know if i'm wrong.

```
success:
          function(data){

            $("#content").load("<?= site_url('sp_profile/ajax_userdetail')?>");
            $("#content2").load("<?= site_url('sp_profile/ajax_userdetail')?>");
            $("#content3").load("<?= site_url('sp_profile/ajax_userdetail')?>");
          }
```

i stuck with this thing for whole day..

please anyone show me the right way to do the controller and js code.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here, use load on its own, not in the success method.

So for example...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content").load("<?= site_url('sp_profile/ajax_userdetail')?>");
  $("#content2").load("<?= site_url('sp_profile/ajax_userdetail')?>");
  $("#content3").load("<?= site_url('sp_profile/ajax_userdetail')?>");
});
```

See [this link](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Just remember that load does a GET and not a POST.